# Limited browser functionality when developing in Windows 8

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, windows-8

Has anyone else run into this problem and resolved it?

I am developing with Visual Studio 2010 in a clean install of RTM of Windows 8.  While developing an ASP.NET application and RUNNING it with the Debugger Attached, I can not click on HTML links in ANY application and have it open up a browser window.

I will be running(debugging through VS) my application in Firefox, and I can't click on links sent in Google Talk or Outlook.

If I stop the application from running, I can then click on those links.

I have also seen that while debugging, I am using jQuery Drag-N-Drop HTML 5 functionality in my application.  I can't use that functionality while it is running under the debugger, it just doesn't work.  This happens with all browsers (Chrome, Firefox and IE).  But if I stop debugging, and run it without the debugger on, it then works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running VS and/or the browser As Administrator?

Comment: yes, I am running VS as administrator.  Not the browser though.  Which is what I find funny, my account that I am logged into my computer is an Administrator account and I have to specifically tell VS to run as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the debuging for "Javascript" in Visual Studio 2012.